# How to display the contents of a web page using a sub-doc and PHP

Tags: php, html

I have been working on a website that will bypass the filtering at my school. Normally, I would not have a problem with filtering, but they block sites (like stack overflow) and others. I have made it so that my fellow students can login using their student credentials, but I don't know how to actually display the web page inside of the main website. I have made a form on another file, in which they login and then input the url of the site they want to retrieve.

I have almost nothing done, but here is what is done.

```
<?php
$target_url = $_POST['url'];
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head> <title> PHP Site Unblocker </title>
</head>
<body> </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do, where is this PHP code hosted?

Comment: The problem is, it's simply not that simple. There are numerous scripts that will only work on the target domain. You have to consider CSS/JavaScript files that run, websocket connections, among many other things. You would need to proxy all those requests.

Comment: I have a better time finding my way around a dark rabbit hole. Honestly, where's the rest of your code?